# Как сделать раскрывающийся список на css правильным?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Имеется раскрывающийся абзац на `css`

```css
.hide,
.hide + label ~ p {
  display: none;
}
.hide:checked + label + p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hd-1" class="hide">ТЕсттектстектстектстектстектстектстектстектстектстектстектс
  <label for="hd-1">
    <img src="https://ru.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico" alt="Читать далее">
  </label>
  <p>
    <br>Новыйновыйновыйновыйновый
    <br>
    <br>ЕщеЕщеЕщеЕщеЕщеЕще.</p>
</div>
```

И есть раскрывающийся список

```css
.hide,
.hide + label ~ p {
  display: none;
}
.hide:checked + label + p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>Название:
  <ul>
    <li>пункт 1.</li>
    <li>пункт 2</li>
    <li>пункт 3.</li>
    <li>
      <input id="hd-2" class="hide" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="hd-2">
        <img src="https://ru.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico" alt="Читать далее" />
      </label>
      <p class="dotted">пункт 4.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как подправить раскрывающийся список, так, чтобы он красиво отображался при раскрытии (желательно с помощью стилей)? пока у меня коряво получается
[Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/h3dqx79s/)

Comment: если вам нужен _список_ - используйте для этого элемент списка: `<ul>`,`<ol>`

Comment: Ну пока видно, что вы пытаетесь отверткой гвоздь забить. Опишите подробнее что вы имеете ввиду говоря: _чтобы он красиво отображался при раскрытии_.

Comment: дополнил вопрос - надеюсь, так будет понятнее

Comment: вот это не то что вы хотите? https://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/uhykY/

Comment: @Grundy при раскрытии сейчас напротив точки - иконка вики, а пункт меню ниже. хочется добиться того, чтобы при раскрытии список выглядел цельным

Comment: @Batanichek нет, не совсем - мне нужно часть списка держать в открытом виде, а часть в свернутом, как в абзаце с кодом выше

Comment: @Вася что вы подразумеватее под "красиво"? Стоит понятней и более развернуто ставить задачу, если вы претендуете на четкое и удовлетворяющее вас решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Красота - понятие, все-таки, субъективное. Постарайтесь ставить задачу более конкретно. Я считаю способ ниже довольно симпатичным. Надеюсь, поможет. И еще, лучше скрывать `checkbox` с помощью абсолютного позиционирования и "уведенияУ в сторону, нежели применять `display: none` - это чревато проблемами на некоторых мобильных устройствах и электронных книгах.

[Код-перо](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/JXMOpo?editors=1100)

P.S. со списком понятно - хотите "красиво". А с абзацем?

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

div {
  width: 300px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
a, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 120px;
}
div, li {
  font: 26px/1.5 'Segoe Ui', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.level1 a {
  border-right: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.level1 a::after {
  content:"\e766";
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  right: -8px;
  color: transparent;
}
.level1 a:hover {
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.level1 a:hover::after {
  right: 0px;
  color: #333;
}
.hide {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.hide + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.hide + label img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    top: 5px;
    left: -36px;
}
.hide + label::before {
  content:'';
  height: 2px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.hide + label::after {
  content:"\e764";
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  right: -3px;
  top: 8px;
  color: transparent;
}

.hide + label:hover::after {
  top: 0px;
  color: #333;
}
.hide + label ~ p {
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: -10px;
  opacity: 0; 
}
.hide:checked + label::before {
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  bottom: -40px;
}
.hide:checked + label::after {
  top: 0px;
  color: #333;
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.hide:checked + label + p {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div>Название:
  <ul>
    <li class="level1"><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li class="level1"><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
    <li>
      <input id="hd-2" class="hide" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="hd-2"><img src="https://ru.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico" alt="Читать далее" /> Wiki</label>
      <p class="level1"><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: да, вот так все ок- спасибо! с абзацем все хорошо))